# Google Plus login Apple now rejecting flip to Safari

Tags: ios, xcode, google-plus

I have an app on the App Store (search for MTHS) that uses Google+ login.
The login feature was accepted in Aug 2014.
I submitted a bug fix in Dec 2014, and Apple rejected it for "flipping over to Safari to login":

*We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:
The app opens a web page in mobile Safari for creating an account or logging in, then returns the user to the app. The user should be able to create an account or log in without opening Safari first.*

Is there a way to implement Google+ login and not have the flip to Safari?
I have seen it in other apps.

Comment: Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900

Comment: Have you got any solution here? facing same issue.

Comment: Same issue here, 5 months later. We've successfully submitted 5 versions of our app using Google+ login and on the 6th they suddenly rejected it. Completely arbitrary.

Comment: Noted on the issue that @abraham referenced, we launched a new iOS Sign In SDK today that supports fallback to WebView, rather than flipping to Safari. Check it out -- we're looking forward to feedback: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios

Comment: @John Hjelmstad not working even I used latest

Comment: @Bhavesh Lathigara: Try this link and download  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/google_signin_sdk_2_1_0.zip It has sample code as well. It works for me.

Comment: ok will check, but when I searched for google login sdk it will show me always 1.7.1 for latest. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 7):

The Google has released the latest **Sign In SDK** which resolves this problem.

Google Sign In SDK 2.0 is documented on the new dev site :

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

Hope this helps..

Comment: Direct link to SDK download: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/google_signin_sdk_2_1_0.zip It has sample code as well. It worked for me.

Comment: @Learner: I have integrated the GooglePlus framework, and due to this redirection issue my app is rejected. Now in your given sdk the classes of GooglePlus is not present in SDK. So do i replace all the code for new google sign or same sdk is available for GooglePlus framework?

Answer (score 0):

Your app should be accepted if you notify the user first that the action will take them out of the app. A simple UIAlertView with a cancel and ok that continues with the Google+ login should work. An app we have does something similar and it was accepted after adding an alert.

Edit: Apple will reject any app that shifts to another app (e.g. launching another app like safari) without first notifying the user and giving them a choice with a label such as "This action will take you out of the app, continue?". In regards to this question, @Learner has the correct solution. At time of original answer, the new SDK wasn't yet available.

Comment: Hi, are you sure about this answer? I am facing same problem

Comment: Please see my edit, @Learner has the correct solution for this question.